# pyflink hive catalog - java gateway issue

Tags: python, hive, apache-flink

I'm trying flink with python in order to replace some workflows, using HiveCatalog according to apache documentation.

Using flink 1.18.0 with python 3.10 on a kubernetes cluster with access to hive 3.1.3.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code:

```
`   env.add_jars("file:///usr/app/flink-sql-connector-hive-3.1.3_2.12-1.18.0.jar")
    env.add_jars("file:///usr/app/libfb303-0.9.3.jar")
    env.add_jars("file:///usr/app/hive-exec-3.1.0.jar")
    
    catalog = HiveCatalog("default", 'db_test', "/usr/app/hive-conf")
`
```

I get the following error:

```
`Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1224, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1038, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1228, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/app/main.py", line 296, in <module>
    hive()
  File "/usr/app/main.py", line 251, in hive
    catalog = HiveCatalog("default", 'db_test', "/usr/app/hive-conf")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyflink/table/catalog.py", line 1209, in __init__
    j_hive_catalog = gateway.jvm.org.apache.flink.table.catalog.hive.HiveCatalog(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1664, in __getattr__
    raise Py4JError("{0} does not exist in the JVM".format(new_fqn))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: org.apache.flink.table.catalog.hive.HiveCatalog does not exist in the JVM
`
```

Any help would be appreciated